# tkinter button not showing GIF image

Tags: image, button, tkinter

here is my code :

```
from Tkinter import *
t = Tk()
imageb=PhotoImage("./CallforHelp.GIF")
b= Button(t, text="Click me", image=imageb, compound=CENTER)
b.configure(image=imageb)
b.pack()
t.mainloop()
```

however the window appears and the button appears with the text , but the image doesn't appear. i tried resizing the button also but nothing changed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you cannot have both the `text` and `image` args. You can only have one of them at a time.